# Split an array column wise in c

Tags: c, matrix

Consider I have an array
A={-4, 2, 2},
{3, -3, 3},
{6, 6, 0 } I want to access column wise.Col={-4,2,2} col_0={3,-3,3} col_1={6,6,0} I have tried something like this yet I am not getting output Can anyone help me. I am beginner in c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define rows 3 
#define col 3

int main()
{
   int matrix_A[rows][col]=
 {
    {-4, 2, 2},
    {3, -3, 3},
    {6, 6, 0}
};
int col[rows];
int col_0[rows];
int col_1[rows];
int n;
for(n=0;n<rows;++n)
{
    col[n]=matrix_A[n][0];
    col_0[n]=matrix_A[n][1];
    col_1[n]=matrix_A[n][2];
}
print("%lf",col[n]);
print("%lf",col_0[n]);
print("%lf",col_1[n]);
```

}

Comment: col[i] is actually same as matrix_A[i], Check this tutorial: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-multi-dimensional-arrays
PS: col is actually row in your case. That's not how 2d array works.

Comment: `n` will be 3 after the loop so it will be out of bounds, as index is 0...2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define rows 3
#define cols 3

int main()
{
    int matrix_A[rows][cols] = {
        {-4, 2, 2},
        {3, -3, 3},
        {6, 6, 0}
    };
    int col_0[rows];
    int col_1[rows];
    int col_2[rows];
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < rows; n++) {
        col_0[n] = matrix_A[n][0];
        col_1[n] = matrix_A[n][1];
        col_2[n] = matrix_A[n][2];
    }
    printf("col_0 = %d %d %d\n", col_0[0], col_0[1], col_0[2]);
    printf("col_1 = %d %d %d\n", col_1[0], col_1[1], col_1[2]);
    printf("col_2 = %d %d %d\n", col_2[0], col_2[1], col_2[2]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
col_0 = -4 3 6
col_1 = 2 -3 6
col_2 = 2 3 0
```

Please note the values of the first column or col_0 is {-4, 3, 6}, not {-4, 2, 2}.
The same with the second and the third.